# Возможно ли проксировать websocket через Apache?

Tags: linux, .htaccess, debian, websocket, apache2

Доброго времени суток. Вопрос несколько странный, но все же. Глядите: есть сервер, стоит за NAT, на нем крутятся Apache 2.4.25 и какой-то вебсокет сервер, не суть какой, т.к работает он корректно. Извне есть доступ, соответственно, только к 80/443 портам. Вопрос: возможно ли настроить апач так, чтобы он спокойно проксировал **wss://example.com:443/ws** на свой же **wss://127.0.0.1:2943**?

Напрямую, без прокси все работает чудесно. С конфигом, приведенным ниже, отдает **400 Bad Request**, причем, судя по логам, до WS сервера запрос не доходит

```html
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName example.com

        ServerAdmin me@example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        LogLevel debug

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

<ifmodule mod_proxy_wstunnel.c>
        <Location /ws>
                ProxyPass wss://127.0.0.1:1234/ws/
                ProxyPassReverse wss://127.0.0.1:1234/ws/
        </Location>
</ifmodule>
<ifmodule mpm_itk_module>
        AssignUserID webserver wheel
</ifmodule>
SSLProxyEngine On
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Ответ сервера:

`HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Fri, 09 Feb 2018 18:55:44 GMT
Server: Apache
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Sec-Websocket-Version: 13
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Length: 12
Connection: close`

Comment: Вместо wss написать ws пробовали?

Comment: @andreymal Пробовал. Та же самая история

Comment: А модуль mod_proxy_wstunnel точно включен? Попробуйте закомментировать соответствующий `if`.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov да, точно, он есть в `apache2 -M`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение найдено.
Данный конфиг осуществляет проксирование ws как нужно.

**!ВАЖНО!**

У вас должен быть включен **mod_proxy_wstunnel**.
Поддержка этого модуля есть в Apache 2.4.25+

```html
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
  <VirtualHost *:443>
   ServerName example.com
   ServerAdmin me@example.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html
   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <ifmodule mod_proxy_wstunnel.c>
      <Location /ws>
        ProxyPass wss://127.0.0.1:1234/ws
        RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto 'https' env=HTTPS
      </Location>
    </ifmodule>

    ProxyVia On ProxyPreserveHost On


    <ifmodule mpm_itk_module>
      AssignUserID webserver wheel
    </ifmodule>
SSLProxyEngine On
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN on
SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire on
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000;
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
  </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```